# What iOS app displays ToDos/Reminders in the Notification Center?

Tags: software-recommendation, ios, notifications, reminders

I need a tasklist/ToDo/Reminders app that lists out my current tasks in the notification center.

I know that Reminders will if I add a time or alarm (I won't want this).

I know Things can if I jailbreak (I don't want to).

I just want a list of things I need to remember to do, right there on the Notifications page.

Answer (score 1):

[Catch Notes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/catch-notes/id355424047?mt=8&uo=4) or [Memo Board](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/memo-board/id376559451?mt=8&uo=4) are the only ones I know of that will stay after the alarm has passed.